# Brand New RAID Array Shows 99% Full (Adaptec ASR-8805)

Tags: raid, adaptec

All -

Just brought a new array online on Windows 11 build.

I created the array in the Adaptec BIOS and did Build/Verify until it was 100% complete.

I saw the drive when I booted into Windows (separate SSD boot drive) and formatted NTFS with default allocation.

Now, when I try to copy data onto the array it crashes after writing a couple of GB.

- Adaptec shows the drive as almost completely full (a few GB of space remaining which is why the copy starts to work)
- Windows (correctly) shows it as empty.
- Bizarrely, Adaptec also shows the drive as 174TB which would include the 2 parity drives (RAID 6) and the hot spare. (Actual RAID size is 130TB of usable space).

I'm kinda stumped here.

Answer (score 0):

> Adaptec shows the drive as almost completely full (a few GB of space remaining
> which is why the copy starts to work)

Adaptec does not care about what happens in a partition. It shows it full because it IS full - you used the space for a RAID partition.

> Windows (correctly) shows it as empty.

Both are correct. Adaptec cased about the "how much is available for RAID partitions", Windows looks into the partition.

> Bizarrely, Adaptec also shows the drive as 174TB which would include the 2
> parity drives (RAID 6) and the hot spare. (Actual RAID size is 130TB
> of usable space).

You do not only not tell us WHERE - which matters - but also - fail to RTFM. This is clearly in the manual. Adaptec shows gross values here. It shows space USED - which is 174TB - not space USABLE (inside). This is useful on a sysop level to plan resource allocation on the physical level. It is CLEARLY documented.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but that doesn't explain why it crashes when I start to copy data to the drive.

Comment: Yeah, because - cough - you do not consider providing baseline information relevant.